# Definition of singly-connected set

Tags: math, cgal

please - help - what does mean singly-connected set? this is set without holes and which has one bounded contour? the sample http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Straight_skeleton_2/index.html#Chapter_2D_Straight_Skeleton_and_Polygon_Offsetting means that this is set of another structure or this docs has mistake?

Comment: wiki get's you a really good explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space ... and ofc this is ot here ;)

Comment: i read the page, but sample of singly-connected set at cgal doc has holes, is this mistake?

Comment: oh sorry - I think they are talking about a different thing there - but it's defined/explained right there

Comment: It looks like it just means "connected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in the Straight skeleton package it means that if you strip off the boundary of the polygon, any two points of the open polygon can be connected with a curve inside the open polygon.

Comment: did you mean the outer boundary? i cannot to understand the definition of open polygon, what is it?